# jQuery multiple ajax load same dynamic page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page which has dynamic content and its content changing with parameters.

I'm trying to comparison different department courses. First I select computer science and load its courses my first div at left. (#list1)

After load first content, I change department to industrial engineering and I click second button to load course list to second div (#list2)

But when i load second div first div content changes like second (industrial engineering). Bu if i load second div first its working! (But its not acceptable for client)

My code like this,

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="list1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="list2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And button click events

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-listele", function () {

        var direction = $(this).attr("data-taraf");
        var send2 = $.post("/Intibak/DersIntibak/CleanIntibakDers");
        send2.done(function () {
        if (direction == "sol") {
            $("#list1").load("/Genel/BolumPlan/IntibakDersPlan?guncelMi=true&groupable=true");
        }
        if (direction == "sag") {
            $("#list2").load("/Genel/BolumPlan/IntibakDersPlan?guncelMi=true&groupable=true");
        }
        });
    });
```

note: if I change div order like above then the problem reverse.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="list2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="list1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

My button code

```
<span class="btn btn-info pull-right btn-listele" id="btn-listele-sol" data-taraf="sol">Ders Planlarını Listele</span>

<span class="btn btn-info pull-right btn-listele" id="btn-listele-sag" data-taraf="sag">Ders Planlarını Listele</span>
```

Comment: whether the first request returns an element with id `list2`

Comment: Try `alert($('[id="list2"]').length)` before loading the second request

Comment: provide your button code.

Comment: @ArunPJohny
i tried different names it same.
and the alert return zero.

Comment: @Chayan
i added my button code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Script Execution](http://api.jquery.com/load/)**

When calling `.load()` using a URL without a suffixed selector expression, the content is passed to `.html()` prior to scripts being removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If `.load()` is called with a selector expression appended to the URL, however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated, and thus are not executed. An example of both cases can be seen below:

Here, any JavaScript loaded into `#a` as a part of the document will successfully execute.

```
$( "#a" ).load( "article.html" );
```

However, in the following case, script blocks in the document being loaded into `#b` are stripped out and not executed:

```
$( "#b" ).load( "article.html #target" );
```

Comment: thanks i added my target page container div a id and put it my load code. it solved.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that what you're loading into '#list1' and '#list2' comes from the exact same data source.

Is the result of `/Genel/BolumPlan/IntibakDersPlan?guncelMi=true&groupable=true"` ever different? If not, you will end up with the same data in each div.

Comment: that page has different contents. i am checking and its working good. before i click list button, i change the department.